# Ssh to multiple hosts and run command based on hostnames

Tags: shell, ssh, ksh, aix

I am trying to ssh to multiple servers and create a new folder having the hostname I am ssh-ing as its name.

I'm using the following ksh script:

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh
for i in `cat $1`
do
ssh $i "sudo mkdir $i"
done
```

This yells `Usage: mkdir [-p] [-e] [-m mode] Directory ...` when running the ./myscript hostnameList

I'm pretty sure this has something to do with the $i variable but not sure how can I use it.

Comment: How about debugging? E.g. `ksh -xv ./myscript`

Comment: Your hostnameList file came from WinDos, innit? You have to remove the CR (\x0d or \r) characters.

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to include a sample input file which produces this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's missing a `do` in the for loop.

Try it:

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh
for i in `cat $1`; do
    ssh $i "sudo mkdir $i"
done
```

https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/ksh-for-loop/

Also make sure you are using double quotes, as in your example.

Comment: There is a `do` in the question.

Comment: So would be important to include the input file. Perhaps you are trying to create a directory inside a non existent directory.

For example:
    `mkdir /tmp/test1/test2`

If test1 doesnt exist, you need to include a `-p` parameter on mkdir command.

Try:
    #!/usr/bin/ksh
    for i in `cat $1`; do
        ssh $i "sudo mkdir -p $i"
    done

`-p, --parents`
no error if existing, make parent directories as needed